# Calling multiple functions onclick event Reactjs - react datepicker

Tags: reactjs, onclick, datetimepicker

I need to gray out the background when the calender opens up - on click, for that I am trying to write a js function and call it along with the actual onclick handler - combining it. But it does not work, I do not have control over the onclick handler as I am using react package? how to handle this case? please help...

```
class CustomDatePicker extends Component {

  handleOpacity(){
    // gray out the background page....
    alert('test');
  }

  click(){
    this.handleOpacity();
  }


  render () {
    return (
        <span>  
            <button className="custom-datepicker" onClick={this.props.onClick} >
             {this.props.value}
            </button>
        </span>
       )
    }
 }
CustomDatePicker.propTypes = {
  onClick: React.PropTypes.func,
  value: React.PropTypes.string
}

export default CustomDatePicker;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call this.props.onClick inside this.click method.
You should also bind this.click in constructor method because you are using ES2015 class syntax for react components.

```
class CustomDatePicker extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.click = this.click.bind(this)
  }

  handleOpacity(){
    // gray out the background page....
    alert('test');
  }

  click(){
    this.handleOpacity();
    this.props.onClick();
  }


  render () {
    return (
        <span>  
            <button className="custom-datepicker" onClick={this.click} >
             {this.props.value}
            </button>
        </span>
       )
    }
 }
CustomDatePicker.propTypes = {
  onClick: React.PropTypes.func,
  value: React.PropTypes.string
}

export default CustomDatePicker;
```

Comment: what if first one is asynchronous ?..i want the second one to be executed only after the first one gets successfully completed.