# React - JSON file won't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onclick, use-state

I am building out a row of react-icons. When selected the icons to display content from a static .JSON file. I am trying to combine the following events:

1. Change color when clicked
2. Change/Switch between the static .JSON content when clicked.

I tried to combine the 2 actions inline based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396924/calling-multiple-functions-onclick-event-reactjs-react-datepicker).

However, only the color changes, not the .JSON data.
Thank you in advance, any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Here is my code below:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../Styles/arrow.css";
import { BsFillPeopleFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { GiLinkedRings } from "react-icons/gi";


import { GoArrowRight } from "react-icons/go";

function Icon(props) {
  const handleClick = (messageKey) => () => props.setSelectedIcon(messageKey);
  const [bg, changeBGColor] = React.useState(1);

  return (
    <div className="icon-arrow">
      <div className="arrow">
        <div className="arrow-line" />
        <div className="arrow-icon">
          <GoArrowRight />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="icons">
        <GiLinkedRings
          className="rings"
          onClick={() => {
            handleClick("rings");
            changeBGColor(1);
          }}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: bg === 1 ? "#e3e1dc" : "#ae7a67",
          }}
        />

        <BsFillPeopleFill
          className="family"
          onClick={() => {
            handleClick("family");
            changeBGColor(2);
          }}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: bg === 2 ? "#e3e1dc" : "#ae7a67",
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Icon;
```

**My .JSON Data: iconmessage.json**

```
{
"rings": {
  "image": "rings.jpg",
    "title" : "Rings",
    "message":"Lorem Ipsum"
},
"family": {
  "image": "family.jpg",
    "title" : "Family is essential",
    "message":"Lorem Ipsum"
}
```

}

**Icons/.JSON being pulled from IconMessage.JSX**

```
import React from "react";
import "../Styles/iconmessage.css";
import messages from "../Static/iconmessage.json";


function IconMessage(props) {

const message = messages[props.selectedIcon]

return (
    <div className="icon-message">
        <div className="title-message">
            <div className="title">{message.title}</div>
            <div className="message">{message.message}</div>

        </div>

        <div className="image">
            <img src={`/images/${message.image}`} alt="" srcset="" />
        </div>

    </div>
   )
}
export default IconMessage
```

Comment: this should work, can you show the other component where you pass props to this component? There is probably something wrong with the JSON data

Comment: Are you passing the setter through props correctly?

Comment: I updated to show my .json file

Answer (score 0):

What you did what correct from the onClick perspective. I'd say that the problem is the value you pass. Are you sure that when you pass "rings" to selectedIcon, it should render the JSON as you'd wish?

I think the problem is that you access messages.title, messages.message, instead of messages.image.title, messages.image.message.

Comment: Can you add the code that uses selectedIcon?

Comment: I added the code now. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I’ve edited my answer. Take a look. Please describe what happened and if it helped.